# Understanding Fischer-Yates shuffle

Tags: javascript

I have this method:

```
shuffleDeck: function()
        {
            var counter = this.deck.length, temp, index;
            while(counter > 0)
                {
                    index = Math.floor(Math.random() * counter);
                    counter--;
                    temp = this.deck.getcard(counter);
                    this.deck.getcard(counter) = this.deck.getcard(index); //*
                    temp = this.deck.getcard(index);
                }
},
```

which gives me an error on the line marked with a *. I know why I get the error (left hand of the = is incorrect), but I do not understand the Fischer-Yates shuffle completely, so I was wondering if someone could walk me through my code!
Thanks

Comment: What exactly is your question?  The line of code with an error is simply wrong and not legal javascript.  There are fully completed Fischer-Yates implementations in Javascript all over the web.  Why not just borrow an already tested implementation like this: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/

Comment: This one has a video visualization http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=1356

Comment: thanks the video was very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to understand it to implement it?

The algorithm is simply pick one card at a time randomly from the set of cards left and put it on your shuffled pile. What your implementation is doing is:

1. start at the back of the deck (counter = length-1, by the time it's swapped with)
2. randomly pick a card from 0 to counter-1, i.e. any card up until the card we're pointing at
3. swap this card with the card at counter-1, i.e. place it at the back
4. reduce counter - i.e. leave that card where it is - and repeat until you reach the front of the deck.

building up the shuffled pile at the back of your deck of cards one card at a time.

You probably need to change the * line and the line after to

```
this.deck.setcard(counter, this.deck.getcard(index));
this.deck.setcard(index, temp);
```

(I'm guessing the `setcard` method and its parameters.)